# Why is Nat type equal to Int in Liquid Haskell?

Tags: haskell, liquid-haskell

Why does this pass Liquid Haskell verification?

```
{-@ sub :: Nat -> Nat -> Int @-}                                                                                                         
sub :: Int -> Int -> Int 
sub i j = i - j
```

Does it mean that `Nat` is the same as `Int` from LH's point of view?

Comment: The documentation specifies that `[lq| type Nat = {v:Int | 0 <= v} |]`, so it is a *subset*.

Comment: Your annotation states that if you take the difference of two `Nat`s, the result is an `Int`, which looks correct. By contrast, `Nat -> Nat -> Nat` would fail. Hence, they are not the same.

Comment: hm, makes sense, so why this snippet passes verification? What will happen if I call `sub` somewhere with `-1` as arguments? LH should fail? May be LH does not require to match the signature totally?

Comment: @chi seems that `sub` in LH is "subset" of `sub` in Haskell (if we can say it)? And both functions signatures may be little bit different (I tried `Float` and LH detects error).

Comment: @Paul-AG: that is because the "root type" is `Int`, as is specified by `v:Int`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so it's not like `newtype` but like `type`? And another question: LH wants to match the type of result totally and fails if subrange of result does not match refinement type in contract. But it is satisfied just with _root type_ when it matches types of arguments?

Comment: @Paul-AG It's not a totally different type (`newtype`) or a synonym for an existing type (`type`).  It's a refinement type.  That is, it's a value of the same type with a refinement - additional restrictions on the value. It type checks if Liquid Haskell can prove that all the refinements are valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you say to me, "Hey, I'd like an apple!". I reply: "Sorry, I only have *red* apples.". You're going to look at me pretty funny, huh? A red apple *is* an apple!

If a function asks for an `Int` as an argument, it's no problem to hand it an `Int` that you know is not negative.